# Using exe from Nuget package as pre-build tool

Tags: automation, nuget

I want to redistribute a tool with nuget, used for auto-generation our code. It generates code in pre-build event. 
I can create nuget package with exe file inside, but how I can use it in pre-build events?

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a Chocolatey package, not a NuGet package. Chocolatey is for executable 'stuff', and NuGet is for build dependencies.